# Understanding Promise.Resolve vs regular callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm new to Promises and currently I have an object that looks like this:

```
Animals{food:{...}, recreation:{...}, toys:{...}}
```

Currently to access the attributes I'm running Animals.food, Animals.recreation ect. We recently want to change this to an async call and the recommendation was to use a Promise. So I did the following:

```
function getAnimalFood(){
    return Promise.resolve(this.food)
}

function getFood(id){
   const allFood = this.getAnimalFood();
   return allFood[id]; 
}
```

My question is how do I access the actual promise object from `food` that has the data? [image]

Comment: You ***must*** go through `.then()` when dealing with promises.  Async is async all the way down.

Comment: Your code has several syntax errors that you should correct.

Comment: "*We recently want to change this to an async call*" - what? why? No, there's nothing asynchronous going on in there, so you should not use promises. Using promises doesn't make anything asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getAnimalFood().then(food => {
  console.log(food)
})
```

The Promise's "callback" params can be retrieved from the .then() for resolve() and from the .catch from the reject()

Comment: why is it that if I were to call this.getAnimalFood() from another component this returns null?

Comment: Component as in another class?

Comment: yeah, if I wanted to get the value food in another call, i keep now get promise "pending"

Comment: could you be more clear?